# How to use NGINX with private and internal IPs

Tags: nginx

I have 2 ips one is private and one is public. I want the public IP to serve a static page

```
server {

    listen private.ip:443 ssl;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;



        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name private.ip.207;
        rewrite ^/$ https://private.ip/web?db=prod  redirect;

location / {
        proxy_pass http://private,ip;
        }


}

server {
    listen private:80;

    server_name private.ip;
        return 301 https://private.ip$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen public.ip:80;

    server_name public.ip;


         root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;


location / {
        proxy_pass http://public.ip:80;
        }
```

How do I serve a different static page if the public ip is used?

Answer (score 1):

If your server is behind NAT with a port forward, you have to use the `Host` header matching mechanism of `server_name`.  The only way to do this would have a completely separate configuration that matches `server_name pub.lic.ip.addr;` like so:

```
server {
    listen private:{port};

    server_name pub.lic.ip.addr;

    # ... configure this site.
}
```

... however, this will ONLY work if the public IP address itself is being requested bare, and certain port-forwarding settings *might* disrupt this.

Comment: Ty for you help. So I've tried this but the public keeps trying to go to the private ip. Not sure what is causing this.

Comment: @hedgethenight your configuration is probably bad.  Show us all the configurations you're currently using, and make sure you reload your NGINX config after each configuration.  Also, as I stated, it may be possible that however your network router/firewall/system is NATing the requests to your server, that it will not work properly.  Is this behind a router or is this a VPS or something connected directly to the Internet (and not behind a router)

Comment: Updated the original question with complete configuration, sorry

Comment: @hedgethenight is the Public IP directly on the system or is it NAT'd / port-forwarded from the router to the server?  Because if it's port-forwarded the public IP address bind in `listen` won't work (and you need to actually set up another listen handler on your *private* IP address for the public IP address in server_name but not on listen.

Comment: it is NAT'd / port-forwarded, could you give me an example of of the server block I need or point to an example? Thank you.

Comment: @hedgethenight well... I did.  Check my example in my answer you will see the listen line listens on your private IP for a Host header of the public IP address...